# How to handle Backbone events implementing a google.maps.OverlayView?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js, backbone-events

My Backbone view implements a `google.maps.OverlayView()`.

This view contains a few div's for content and I need to handle mouseover/out on the container div and click events on two containing div's.

The only way I'm able to get the needed events is by using `google.maps.event.addDomListener` in my view. Something like this (copy&paste code):

```
var MarkerView = MasterView.extend({
    events:{
        //These events will never be fired
        'click .icon-context':function () {},
        'mouseout':function (event) {}
    },
    render:function(){
      //this renders the google.maps.OverlayView by implementing onAdd, draw, onRemove 
      var that = this;

      this.overlay.onAdd = function(){
        //Code for adding the OverLayView omitted here

        that.listeners_ = [
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(that.overlay.el, 'mouseout', function () {
            //This event should not be handled here
          }),
          google.maps.event.addDomListener($(that.overlay.el).find('.icon-context').first()[0], 'click', function () {
            //This event should not be handled here
          }),            
        ];

      };

    }
});
```

Core parts of the view logic should be reusable because I'd like to use it on the map and in a list showing/handling almost the same stuff. With binding my view to the Google Maps event listener I would have to duplicate a fair amount of code for the event handling. Feels not exactly right to do so.

How can I make my view handle the events "natively" if the view is hosted inside a `google.maps.OverlayView`

Comment: views have events hash `events:{name:callback}` that is bound to the root element through delegation, so hope it will work

Comment: Unfortunately the `events:{name:callback}` is not working for my custom OverlayView as I tried to show in my code example. Or am I missing something substantial you tried to tell me?

Comment: Overlay gets created after the view is appended into the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this.setElement($(that.overlay.el))` on the view ***after creating and adding the overlay to the HTML*** so the EL is updated so you can use the events hash.

If you instantiate a new overlay you have to do it again to make EL point to the right thing.

Don't forget to wrap it in a Jquery obj, this helped me a lot when trying to add event handlers to infoBoxes

Comment: How easy could it be. Now it works with the events hash. Thanks a lot.